# How to get command line argument when script is executable?

Tags: ruby

I'm working on simple script that setup project structure for me (directories/files). I have an issue with retrieving argument passed as command line argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

project_name = ARGV.first

puts "Provide project name" ; abort if project_name.nil?
```

When I try to run it, I get:

```
$ ./creator test
Provide project name
```

May be I'm not aware of something. When I do without **#!/usr/bin/env ruby**  it works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with wether you execute your script with `$ ./creator test` or `$ ruby creator test`. The problem is that you always just print a static string with `puts "Provide project name"`. I think this is more what you are after:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
project_name = ARGV.first
abort if project_name.nil?
puts "Provide #{project_name}"
```

Here the `project_name` variable is substituted into the string, by doing `#{project_name}`.